# Broadcasting-to multiple peer

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, broadcasting

How can we have a stream in which video and screen share in simultaneously in one single stream using webRTC so it can be send to all the peers in one stream

Answer (score 0):

You need to use canvas html element and blend streams received via calls to getUserMedia (webcam) and getDisplayMedia (screen) into that canvas element.

Then take resulting blended picture from that canvas element and stream it with RTCPeerConnection.

Live example here:
https://unrealstreaming.net:8443/UnrealWebRTCPublishingDemo/publish.aspx

Comment: Can you send me the github repository?

Comment: There is no github repository, you can take the javascript from that site.

Comment: This is just a javascript that blends screen and webcam into a single picture, isn't that what you wanted? It doesn't show you the blended picture?